Wrapper over the application config
Wrapper over the application config.
Config can be a JSON file (or YAML, but I haven't written a policy for YAML yet).
appconfig.h :
    #pragma once
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include "json_policy.h"
    
    
    class AppConfigBase {
    public:
      virtual ~AppConfigBase() = default;
      virtual ConfigNode read(const std::string& key) const = 0;
      virtual bool exist(const std::string& key) const = 0;
    };
    
    template <typename Policy>
    class AppConfig : public AppConfigBase {
    public:
      AppConfig(const std::string& config_path) {
        std::string config_data;
        if (std::ifstream file(config_path); file.is_open()) {
          std::stringstream buffer;
          buffer << file.rdbuf();
          config_data = buffer.str();
          file.close();
        } else {
          throw std::runtime_error("Could not open AppConfig");
        }
        root = Policy::parse(config_data);
      }
    
      ConfigNode read(const std::string& key) const override {
        if (root) {
          auto child = root->getChild(key);
          if (child) {
            return *child;
          }
        }
        return ConfigNode();
      }
    
      bool exist(const std::string& key) const override {
        return root && root->exist(key);
      }
    
    private:
      typename ConfigNode::Ptr root;
    };

confignode.h :
  #pragma once
    #include <memory>
    #include <vector>
    #include <variant>
    #include <unordered_map>
    
    class ConfigNode {
    public:
      using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<ConfigNode>;
      using ValueType = std::variant<std::monostate, bool, int, double, std::string, std::vector<std::string>>;
    
      ConfigNode() = default;
    
      explicit ConfigNode(ValueType val)
          : value(std::move(val)) {
      }
    
      void addChild(const std::string& key, Ptr child) {
        children[key] = std::move(child);
      }
    
      Ptr getChild(const std::string& key) const {
        auto it = children.find(key);
        return it != children.end() ? it->second : nullptr;
      }
    
      bool exist(const std::string& key) const {
        return getChild(key) != nullptr;
      }
    
      bool isLeaf() const {
        return children.empty();
      }
    
      template <typename T>
      bool getValue(T& out) const {
        if (std::holds_alternative<T>(value)) {
          out = std::get<T>(value);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    
      ConfigNode read(const std::string& key) const {
        auto child = getChild(key);
        if (child) {
          return *child;
        }
        return ConfigNode();
      }
    
      template <typename T>
      operator T() const {
        if (std::holds_alternative<T>(value)) {
          return std::get<T>(value);
        } else {
          throw std::runtime_error("Invalid type conversion");
        }
      }
    
      bool isBool() const {
        return std::holds_alternative<bool>(value);
      }
    
      bool isInt() const {
        return std::holds_alternative<int>(value);
      }
    
      bool isDouble() const {
        return std::holds_alternative<double>(value);
      }
    
      bool isString() const {
        return std::holds_alternative<std::string>(value);
      }
    
      bool isArray() const {
        return std::holds_alternative<std::vector<std::string>>(value);
      }
    
      bool empty() const {
        return value.index() == 0;
      }
    
    private:
      ValueType value{std::monostate{}};
      std::unordered_map<std::string, Ptr> children;
    };

json_policy.h :
#pragma once
#include "confignode.h"

#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;

class ConfigNode;

class JsonPolicy {
public:
  static ConfigNode::Ptr parse(const std::string& config_data) {
    json j = json::parse(config_data);
    return build_tree(j);
  }

private:
  static ConfigNode::Ptr build_tree(const json& j) {
    if (j.is_object()) {
      ConfigNode::Ptr node = std::make_shared<ConfigNode>();
      for (auto it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it) {
        node->addChild(it.key(), build_tree(it.value()));
      }
      return node;
    } else if (j.is_boolean()) {
      return std::make_shared<ConfigNode>(j.get<bool>());
    } else if (j.is_number_integer()) {
      return std::make_shared<ConfigNode>(j.get<int>());
    } else if (j.is_number_float()) {
      return std::make_shared<ConfigNode>(j.get<double>());
    } else if (j.is_string()) {
      return std::make_shared<ConfigNode>(j.get<std::string>());
    } else if (j.is_array()) {
      std::vector<std::string> array;
      array.reserve(j.size());
      for (const auto& item : j) {
        array.push_back(item.get<std::string>());
      }
      return std::make_shared<ConfigNode>(array);
    }

    return nullptr;
  }
};


AppConfigBase
I'm not sure I see the point of this class. Presumably, this is to provide runtime polymorphism because AppConfig is templated on Policy. But AppConfig is essentially a read only container for your data. The only difference between a JSON AppConfig and a YAML AppConfig is the how root is constructed in the constructor. If we pull that part out, we don't need AppConfigBase anymore.
So, for example, your AppConfig can just be simple class that contains the root.
class AppConfig {
   explicit AppConfig(ConfigNode::Ptr root): root{std::move(root)}
    {}
    ...
   const ConfigNode::Ptr root;
};

Your JsonPolicy class can remain the same; the only difference is that it's not called in the constructor.
AppConfig app_config{JsonPolicy::parse(config_data)};
// or
AppConfig app_config{YamlPolicy::parse(config_data)};

In fact, you don't even need *Policy classes here since all they contain are static method, a role that can be fulfilled by namespaces.
namespace json_policy {
     ConfigNode::Ptr parse(const string& data) {
           ...
      }
}

int main() {
   AppConfig config; 
   if (/* config is json */) {
       config = std::move(AppConfig{json_policy::parse(json_data)});
   }
}

Now,

your AppConfig does know or care how it gets the data

you have eliminated a virtual method call, especially if you're reading the config in a tight-loop (this is bit of premature optimization, but performance  wins are always nice)



Prefer returning std::optional over out parameters
Prefer using something like std::optional over out parameters. If you're using C++23, you can probably also use std::expected, although I think former is more idiomatic. One small benefit of doing this that the caller does not need to default construct the object before-hand.

Misc.

If you're using C++17, you can pass in std::string_view over const std::string&. The compiler does not have to construct a std::string from a const char* which can potentially avoid unnecessary allocations.

Consider returning const ConfigNode& in the read method. ConfigNode is a pretty hefty objecy and every time you call read, you're making a copy of it, which seems unnecessary for a read-only object.

Consider using std::unique_ptr. If you want to return the allocated object, consider either passing by const reference or just passing a pointer (non-owning raw pointers are mostly fine).

Prefer using include guards. pragma #once is non-standard (although you'll be hard-pressed to find a modern compiler that does not implement it).



I am using c++20. I will correct what you pointed out, it sounds great. thank you

const ConfigNode::Ptr root; Don’t make data members const.
